# ErrorException: Warning: get_cfg_var() has been disabled for security reasons

Tags: php, symfony

I have same issue in symfony hosted in shared host server. I am getting this issue.

ErrorException: Warning: get_cfg_var() has been disabled for security reasons.

I don't have command line access to solve. I need to solve this from ftp server.

Answer (score 1):

You can look in your **php.ini** for **disabled_functions** ans see if you can find **get_cgf_var()** so you can delete it from the list.

However, in your case if you're using shared hosting, you may not be able to change it.

Comment: Yes, Is there any way to fix this issue. Is this php version issue?

Comment: Have you tried what I said first ? Is get_cgf disabled ? can you not access the php.ini ?

Comment: Hi @Dylan, I don't have a permission to access php.ini file because this Application running on shared host server. Any other way to fix this problem. thanks

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have fixed issue this is due to config problem.  we need to disable debug_mode=0 and dev to prod in .env file.